# Add Certificate To HttpWebRequestin C#

Tags: c#, x509, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to add a certificate from my certificate store to a HttpWebRequest object. The certificate is fetched from the store successfully and added the HttpWebRequestobject. But when the request is sent, at the reciving end the certificate is not present. Not sure what's happening in between. Here is my code that fetches the certificate and then dispatches it to a receiving server. The process is for certificate based authentication.(I am trying to authenticate myself with the server)

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
// Look for the first certificate that is named Cartus-to-Microsoft.
// Look in the local machine store.
X509CertificateCollection col = (X509CertificateCollection)store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, true);
X509Certificate cert = null;
try
{
    if(col.Count>0)
        cert = col[0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Certificate not Found!");
}

//HttpWebRequest req = null;
HttpWebResponse rsp = null;
string uri = "http://relofileservice.azurewebsites.net/api/datasync/reloPostService"; //"http://localhost:64952/api/datasync/reloPostService";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

//Add payload to request
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-forum-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
//Build The request Header
req.KeepAlive = false;
req.UserAgent = "Cartus API Client";
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

Trace.TraceInformation("Certificate added to rquest");
try
{
    //Send the request and receive response.
    rsp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    Trace.TraceError("GetResponse Error Message: " + Ex.Message + ". GetResponse Error StackTrace: " + Ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: How do you check the certificate at the other end? Does the certificate have a private key? Why are you using `X509Certificate` and not `X509Certificate2`? Also, you should be using the `X509Certificate2Collection` instead of `X509CertificateCollection`. When you use `X509Certificate2` what is the value of the `HasPrivateKey` property?

Comment: In addition, your code leads to memory leaks, because there is no code that closes certificate store. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.close(v=vs.110).aspx add `finally` block to first try/catch clause.

Comment: HasPrivateKey is true. Should it or should it not contain PrivateKey?

Comment: It should. How are you checking for the certificate at the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There were two steps that needed to be done before sending the certificate. None of the blogs or documents explained these two steps. Its funny how the important bits always get left out in the proposed solutions. Anyway, here are the final tidbits of the solution:

1. Make sure the client certificate is in personal store.
2. Assign rights to read the Private Key for the user account that is trying to read the certificate from the store.

Code wise:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection col = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, true);
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
try
{
    if(col.Count>0)
    cert = col[0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Certificate not Found!");
}

store.Close();
```

And Voila!!!